# upload and display images from database in liferay

Tags: java, mysql, liferay, liferay-6, image-uploading

I have written code for upload and display of images in java. I am using liferay.
Since to my knowledge liferay `service.xml` doesnt have `Blob` I used an alternative way by modifying the `portlet-model-hints.xml` file. Initially the field for storing image was made string which was changed to `Clob` in the above mentioned file. After building services it becomes longtext. I stored the images as longtext and when I try to display the text is displayed. How should I try to display the pics stored in the mysql database?

Answer (score 1):

Create a hook that renders the value of the field as a image (transmute backwards from what you did to store it as text in the first place)

you should check out the liferay jackrabit configuration, maybe it can help you storing the images in the db in the first place

Comment: Matthias G:
Thanks for your reply.
In many of the forums in liferay community, I read that there is no blob type in service.xml
Could you please help me how should i do using jackrabbit?
I am in the process of reading the foll. link:
http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Using+Jackrabbit+with+Database#section-Using+Jackrabbit+with+Database-Steps+to+hooking+up+Jackrabbit+to+MySQL

Can you in short give a summary of what to do? I havent worked with hooks..

Comment: i have not much experience with jackrabbit, all i know is that you need some kind of property in the portal-ext which tells jackrabbit to store images in the db(dl.hook.impl=com.liferay.documentlibrary.util.JCRHook). In addition you will need to do the steps described in your link. Maybe this link [http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/820-7054/gifgn/index.html](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/820-7054/gifgn/index.html) can help you but i think its equivalent to yours.

Comment: Matthis G:
So does that mean that I don't have to use service.xml?

Comment: well if you try the solution with jackrabbit i think you wont need to create a function that stores images in db because liferay/jackrabbit will automatically.

Comment: Matthias G: Thanks for your prompt reply. 
I will read the documentation since I haven't fully understood it. 
Thanks for your guidance

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at `service.xml` related to document library contents ([see online here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.liferay.portal/portal-impl/6.1.0/com/liferay/portlet/documentlibrary/service.xml)), and...

```xml
...
<column name="repositoryId" type="long" />
<column name="path" type="String" />
<column name="version" type="String" />
<column name="data" type="Blob" />
...
```

So it has `Blob` type.
I hope this helps you.

Comment: Dani:
Thanks for the reply. I tried the following code in service.xml file. I do not know how far it is correct:
<entity name="Image" local-service="true" remote-service="true">
  <column name="ImageId" type="long" primary = "true"></column>
  <column name = "imagedesc" type = "String"/>
  <column name = "uploadimage" type = "Blob"/>
        
   <reference package-path="com.liferay.portal" entity="Image" />
</entity>
I built services and when i ran it created a field in the database as longblob for uploadimage column.but it gave lots of errors in services that were generated.wats the solution?

Comment: What kind of errors? Please consider updating your question. I assume you have followed some tutorial like this: http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/service-build-5

Comment: I created a Blob field like the one you suggested in ur previous reply:
<column name="data" type="Blob" />
When i build services I get BUILD SUCCESSFUL message but an error in package com.test.blob.upload in the blobuploadModelImpl class. 
@Override
public void resetOriginalValues() {
blobuploadModelImpl._pictureBlobModel = null;
}
the suggestion is
change modifier of pictureBlobModel to static
this error comes when I give the type of column as Blob.

Comment: Dani:
I had even tried an aternative way by modifying the portlet-model-hints.xml file but it didnt help. it uploads the image successfuly but it is stored as longtext. when i try to display , i do not see the image but string of characters